# What other terminology does a street map help in going through set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graph-theory

I know that a simple street map, can be viewed as a relation on the Cartesian product of the ordered sets of the streets going east-west and north-south ( or pick your directions) respectively. Also, I know they also technically show the path followed. Are there any other terms from set theory that could be learned with them ?  e.g below:

$$\begin{smallmatrix}&oxford&seldon&larch&lilac&preston&chestnut&walnut&garden&lemarchant&vernon&henry&casmus&edward&robie\\quinpool&\square&&&&\square&&&&&\square&&&&\square\\pepperell&\square&\square&&&\square&&&&&\square&&&&\square\\shirley&&&&&\square&\square&\square&\square&&\square&&&&\square\\norwood&\square&\square&&&\square&&&&&&&&&\\linden&&&&&&&&\square&&\square&&&&\\cherry&&&&&&&&&&\square&&&&\square\\york&\square&&&&\square&&&&&&&&&\\cedar&&&&&\square&\square&\square&\square&&\square&&\square&&\square\\cornwall&\square&&&&\square&&&&&&&&&\\jubilee&\square&&\square&&\square&\square&\square&\square&&\square&\square&&\square&\square\\binney&&&&&&&&&&&\square&&\square&\square\\jennings&\square&&\square&&\square&&&&&&&&&\\watt&&&&&\square&\square&\square&&\square&\square&\square&&&\\bliss&&&&&&&&&&&\square&&\square&\square\\payzant&&&\square&\square&\square&\square&&&&&&&&\\coburg&\square&&\square&\square&&\square&\square&&\square&\square&\square&&\square&\square\\\end{smallmatrix}$$

Comment: someone feel free to make the names going across the top vertical somehow ...

Comment: oh and for those trying to read it the squares means the relation  intersects.

Comment: You may want to describe this with a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory). There are two choices: intersections as vertices  and street blocks as edges (which is natural) or streets as vertices and intersections as edges.

Comment: @lhf how do I make the graph without tikzpicture ? I was thinking of adding it to the posting but the best I can think of is implies in different directs or at least the big arrows.

Answer (score 1):

I think a map is, when you get down to its very essence, just a union of [curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve) in the plane or in $3$-space.

Now, if you wish to lend importance to the intersection points of the curves, or other points along the curve that aren't intersections, then the natural interpretation is as a **graph** [in this sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)).  If the map is so informative as to tell you the distances between the landmarks you have placed, then it could even be considered a weighted graph.

If your streets are all assumed to be straight (not very reasonable, I suppose, unless you grew up where I did) then you could interpret it as a collection of intersecting lines in geometry (and a graph at the same time, as above.)

The table you gave above records the incidence relation between the streets chosen. You might want to take a look at how [incidence matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incidence_matrix) encode the same information. The difference would be that instead of streets on both axes, you'd have streets on one axis and intersection labels on the other.

Comment: I see your points I was mostly caring about the set theory that could be defined usefully with one as an example ( had to smallmatrix the data made it too large of an example)

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee I'm gambling (a safe bet I think) that no matter what example I give, set theory will play a role in explaining/describing it :)

Comment: point taken as it underlies ring theory, group theory, field theory, topology , etc.

Comment: to be fair you can also list streets as ordered multisets and get the curve needed to show them all.